# *(x+i) is same as &x[i]?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Question 3 on [Career Ride](https://www.careerride.com/mcq/c-programming-programming-language-mcq-questions-48.aspx) suggests that `*(x+i)` is the same as `&x[i]`. Can someone please explain whether this is correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That answer is incorrect. Given a pointer variable `x` and an integer variable `i`, `*(x + i)` is the same as `x[i]` and `x + i` is the same as `&x[i]`. It looks like they took half from each side of that for their answer, but they didn't provide any explanation, so we'll never know.

Comment: It´s even better: They just say "*Suppose that `x` is a one dimensional array, then choose the correct answer regarding array*" - They do not even imply that `x` shall be an array of pointers.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio it does not matter what type is `x`

Comment: @P__J__ What if `x` is of type `int []`. Does `*(x + i)` work then too? Because of array-to-pointer decay?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio you are asking surprisingly elementary questions. The answer is **YES**. If `x` is an array or pointer `x[i] == *(x + i)`. You should try it yourself before commenting https://godbolt.org/z/-j2bUH

Comment: @P__J__ Just because the array decays to a pointer to the first element does not automatically mean it is valid to use pointer arithmetics with the obtained pointer or to dereference the result of the arithmetical expression. Not sure, if this is standard-compliant.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio it is. It is one of the most frequent used "features". What is the array: `An array  type describes  a  contiguously  allocated  non empty  set  of  objects  with  a particular   member   object   type,   called   the element   type.` Then if the type of the pointer is the same as the array element type. Additionally 6.5.6.8

Answer (score 5):

It not the same:

`*(x+i):` returns the content of the ith element in `x` array/pointer

`&x[i]:` returns the address of the ith element in `x` array/pointer

Answer (score 3):

To be more funny none of the answers on that page is correct. Lovely website :)

a. *(x + n) is same as &x[n] **WRONG**

b. *&x[n] is same as x + n **WRONG**

c. *(x + n) is same as x[n] +1 **WRONG**

d. *(x + n) is same as *x[n] **WRONG**